# packer error "module 'packer.luarocks' not found:"

Tags: neovim, lua, nvchad, packer

I am trying to install packer.nvim to my NvChad configuration.

I installed packer using `git clone https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\packer.nvim"`
and made this packer.nvim file:

```lua
vim.o.runtimepath = vim.fn.stdpath('data') .. '/site/pack/*/start/*,' .. vim.o.runtimepath

return require('packer').startup(function(use)
  -- Packer can manage itself
  use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'

end)
```

and I installed NvChad according to [the installation guide](https://nvchad.com/docs/quickstart/install).

I already installed packer this way before, but when I tried to run :PackerSync i got this error:

```lua
                                                                                                                                   E5108: Error executing lua: Vim(lua):E5108: Error executing lua ...m-data\site\pack\packer\start\packer.nvim/lua/packer.lua:110: module 'packer.luarocks' not found:
        no field package.preload['packer.luarocks']
cache_loader: module packer.luarocks not found
cache_loader_lib: module packer.luarocks not found
        no file '.\packer\luarocks.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\lua\packer\luarocks.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\lua\packer\luarocks\init.lua'
        no file '.\packer\luarocks.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\packer\luarocks.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\loadall.dll'
        no file '.\packer.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\packer.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ...m-data\site\pack\packer\start\packer.nvim/lua/packer.lua:110: in function 'require_and_configure'
        ...m-data\site\pack\packer\start\packer.nvim/lua/packer.lua:576: in function 'sync'
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
        [C]: at 0x7ff660fe8620
stack traceback:
        [C]: at 0x7ff660fe8620
```

I tried solving this by installing luarocks, reinstalling packer, and anything i could think that would solve this issue, but nothing so far worked. can anyone tell me why and how can i install this packer.luarocks package?

Comment: NvChad comes with the [LazyVim](https://github.com/LazyVim/LazyVim) package manager. I would either build my own configuration or keep the selection of my distribution (e.g. NvChad).

Comment: i can try, but i like packer and don't like lazy. I thought it would be better to just keep lazy for NvChad's default configuration and use Packer for my configuration

Comment: This is ambitious :-)